# Jmeter regular expression issue

Tags: jmeter

I'm working with Jmeter in order to put in a variable the value *5F0588B01C51975BC6A9397546E513FF* present in the following body response:

```
<form id="command" name="command" action="/Application/app/cc/payment/form?_S_T_=5F0588B01C51975BC6A9397546E513FF" method="post">
```

Usually, I got the value just with reg-expression: **(.+?)** , but in this case, it does not work.
The variable contains an empty result.
For example, this is the regular expression I used:

```
<form id="command" name="command" action="/Application/app/cc/payment/form?_S_T_=(.+?)" method="post">
```

Could you please indicate to me where i'm wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `?` has special meaning in Regex, then if you want to consider it as a normal character, you have to escapse it. `\?`

Some solutions can work:

```
<form id="command" name="command" action="/Application/app/cc/payment/form\?_S_T_=(.+?)" method="post">
```

```
form\?_S_T_=(.+?)"
```

or change `?` to `.` : match any character

```
form._S_T_=(.+?)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!!!  I spent a lot of time yesterday to find out a solution.  Many thanks.